# Изменение цвета кнопки трекбаром через Color.FromArgb C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Необходимо правильно масштабировать ползунок. Задача следующая, при перемещении ползунка с диапазоном от 0 до 10 необходимо менять цвет кнопки. Необходимо в каждый канал цвета передавать значения от 0-255. Пока получилось, но не знаю как масштабировать третий канал упирается в предел 174.

```
 public class ColorCalculator
{
    public int First { get; set; }
    public int Second { get; set; }
    public int Third { get; set; }

    public void Test(int val)
    {
        First = (int)76.5 * val;
        int buf = 0;

        if (First >= 255)
        {
            buf = First;
            First = 255;
            Second = buf - First;
        }

        if (Second >= 255)
        {
            buf = Second;
            Second = 255;
            Third = buf - Second;
        }

        if (Third >= 255)
        {
            Third = 255;
        }
    }
}
```

Мейн

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ColorCalculator c;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        c = new ColorCalculator();
    }

    private void GetNumber()
    {
        /// Максимальное число 3 х 255 = 765 / 10
        var temp = 76.5;
        c.Test(trackBar1.Value);
        button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(c.First, c.Second, c.Third);

    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = c.First.ToString();
        label2.Text = c.Second.ToString();
        label3.Text = c.Third.ToString();
        GetNumber();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если ползунок тащить в обратном направлении, значения не обнуляются. Не пойму как это сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Два момента.

Первый: Вы считываете значения свойств (`First`,...) *до* их вычисления.

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetNumber();
    label1.Text = c.First.ToString();
    label2.Text = c.Second.ToString();
    label3.Text = c.Third.ToString();
}
```

Второй: Отбрасывать дробную часть надо *после* умножения.

```
First = (int)(76.5 * val);
```

Comment: Второе ясно, а первый пункт нет. Я же в событие использую Value трекбара. Даже если я в метод тест кину рассчитанное значение `c.Test((int)(76.5 * trackBar1.Value));` Ничего не меняется.

Comment: Пока это больше похоже на указание направления в какой стороне находится ответ (и судя по комментариям топикстартера - не понятое), чем на ответ. - из очереди проверок.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы! Пока не ясна проблема. Потому что имеет место быть проблеме 0 значений, и масштабирование последнего значения до 255.

Comment: @JDo `label1.Text` присваивается до вызова `GetNumber`, а, соответственно, до вычисления `c.First`. Поэтому последняя позиция ползунка не учитывается